# minio get object function timeouts

Tags: python, pickle, minio

I have stored several pickles of my machine learning models in a google bucket.

At inference time I simply use the command:

```
minio_obj.fget_object(bucket, object_name=element.object_name, file_path=path)
```

This works for 99 out of 100 different pickled files. The one time that this doesn't work, the download simply hangs and timeouts.

The bucket contains:

```
project1/
    model1.pickle
    model2.pickle
project2/
    model1.pickle
    model2.pickle
etc
```

At inference, I get each list of the object from the folder I need, and I download them in an iterative manner (as shown in the example). The element in the example is the pickled model that I have in my folder.

*Important Notes*

1. I have noticed that if I change the name of my pickled file from the buckets' web interface, it will work perfectly.
2. It is *not* a unicode issue I've thoroughly checked (all the names contain strictly Latin alphabet anyway).
3. An overview of the code is this:

   ```
   object_list = list(minio_obj.list_objects(bucket, start_after=base_path, recursive=True))
   object_list = [i for i in object_list if base_path in i.object_name]

   for element in object_list:
     name = element.object_name
     path = f"{models_basic_path}/{name}"
     minio_obj.fget_object(bucket, object_name=element.object_name, file_path=path)
   ```

Comment: You could check if you MinIO console has any error messages related to the hanging request. Or even better, try to download the same object with the MinIO client tool - `mc cp --debug myminio/mybucket/myfilepath /tmp/` and see what the debug messages say.

Comment: It seems that the reason that i had this problem was due to my kubectl port forwarding...